# Поиск подстроки во всех таблицах базы данных

Tags: mysql

Как осуществить поиск некоторой подстроки во всех текстовых полях всех таблиц некоторой базы данных ?

P.S. Задача одноразовая, ПО наподобие sphinx'a использовать не планирую :=)

Comment: А опишите, какую задачу Вы хотите таким образом решить? Возможно, есть более экономный способ, позволяющий не перелопачивать всю БД.

Comment: В одной из таблиц базы содержится строка. Это не вредоносный код. Нужно найти в какой таблице находится эта строка.

Answer (score 1):

Одним запросом - никак. Можно или сформировать (руками или shell-скриптом) по запросу на каждую таблицу вида `SELECT * from tbl_name WHERE field1 LIKE 'string' OR field2 LIKE 'string' OR field...n LIKE 'string'`и выполнять их по очереди, или воспользоваться чем-нибудь вроде phpMyAdmin - там такая функциональность есть из коробки, достаточно в web-интерфейсе задать строку для поиска.

Работает, конечно, дико медленно, но Вы говорите, что задача одноразовая - что ж.